# Can kernel of homomorphism tell you when a group action cannot be constructed?

Tags: group-theory, group-actions, abstract-algebra

I understand that for every action of group $G$ on a set $X$, there is a homomorphism:
$$G\rightarrow S_X$$
It seems to me that this can be used to rule out many possible actions. For example, a group of order 11 could not act on a set of cardinality 3, because then the kernel of the homomorphism would have to be of order $|\{e\}|+(|G|-|S_X|)=1+11-3!=1+11-6=6$. 6 does not divide 11, violating LaGrange's theorem.

Is this correct?

Comment: Thanks! That answers my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, to answer the question in the title "Can kernel of homomorphism tell you when a group action cannot be constructed?" No, its isomorphism class cannot: For example, $S_X\times H$ acts on the set $X$ with kernel $H$, no matter the group $H$.

---

Now, to address the rule you give: you have a slight error (aside from the missing non-triviality assumption). For example, $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$, the cyclic group of order $12$, acts on the set of three elements by permuting two of them (and leaving the third fixed). However, $1+12-6=7$ and $7$ does not divide $12$$^{\dagger}$.

I believe that the condition you are after is the following:

> A group $G$ acts non-trivially on a set $X$ if there exists a proper normal subgroup $N\lhd G$ such that $G/N$ embeds into $S_X$.

From this, you have the following necessary condition:

> $|G|$ and $|X|$ are not coprime (why?).

In my example, there is a homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}_{12}\twoheadrightarrow\mathbb{Z}_2$ and $\mathbb{Z}_2$ embeds into $S_3$, while in your example $\mathbb{Z}_{11}$ is simple and cannot embed into $S_3$, hence it cannot act non-trivially on the set with three elements (note that $11$ and $3$ are coprime).

Note that the necessary condition is not sufficient. For example, $A_5$, the alternating group of order $60$, is simple and so if it acts non-trivially on a set then the kernel of the action must be trivial. This means that if $A_5$ acts on $X$ then $A_5$ embeds into $S_X$. Then, $4$ is not coprime to $60$, but $A_5$ cannot embed into $S_4$ (a group of order $24$), and hence any action of $A_5$ on a set of order less than $5$ is trivial. The same is true for any $A_n$, $n\geq5$, acting on sets of order less than $n$.

---

$^{\dagger}$The "reason" that the formula does not work is because actions need a "multiplicative" formula, because they are related to $G/N$, but the given formula is additive. One way to exploit this additivity to get a counter-example would be to take larger and larger sets $X$ for fixed $G$, and see that the formula gives a negative number. Even if $|G|>|X|$, negative numbers are possible, because $|X|!\gg|X|$.

Comment: I will have to study your answer more - but it is still always the case that the order of the kernel must divide the order of the group, right? Can you maybe note how that still holds in your explanation?

Comment: Applying my above formula to $C_{10}$ acting on a set of size 3, I get $1+10−3!=5$ which does divide 10.

Comment: Yes, it must always hold! An action on a group on a set is simply a homomorphism $G\rightarrow S_X$. This homomorphism has a kernel, which must be a normal subgroup (by the first isomorphism theorem). Does that make sense?

Comment: @Gerber Hmm, sorry, it seems that I didn't see your factorial. Just take $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$ then. Or, a better counter-example would be $|G|=2$. Then $1+2-n!$ is odd for all $|X|>2$. In fact, just take larger and larger sets, and you end up with negative numbers!

Comment: I think I see now. Does the formula make sense as a check for $|S_X|<|G|$? Your approach is much better, though, but just wondering.

Comment: Never mind - your edit just answered that.

Comment: @Gerber No, I do not think so. Actions are "multiplicative", because they are related to $G/N$, and your formula is additive. (In fact, take $G$ to have one more element than $X$, and take $X$ to be massive! Then $n!>>(n+1)$.)